# I have 3 primary partitions already, can i shrink one of them and install kali-linux?

Tags: partition, dual-boot, kali-linux

I have 3 primary partitions and 2 logical partitions already in my windows 8.1 PC. But now i want to shrink a 20gb space from c drive and install kali-linux 2.0 in it.. i tried to install kali linux on the unlocated space i have shrunked, but on kali drive selection process it shows the unlocated space as unusable.. but now i merged the unlocated space to c drive back coz it didn't helped.. can u help me to solve the problem regarding my installation problem.. i m trying to install kali-linux from a usb flash drive..[image: my disk management screenshot is here.]

Comment: From that image it looks like you have not shrunk anything yet, but your text says you already did shrink some ("space i have shrunked"). First make sure you have actually shrunk enough space.

Comment: i shrunk once but i rolled the changes back coz it didn't helped..

Comment: why don´t you move the d drive after shrinking, extend the extended and install kali inside there? Like @Henrik says it used to be a maximum of 4, it changed but chances are Microsoft Computer Management still keeps the old standard (don´t know for sure, I don´t do partitioning in windows).

Answer (score 0):

With the old partitioning scheme there can be a maximum of four primary partitions (of which one can be used as an extended - I'm actually not sure you can't use more than one, but the use cases aren't clear to me), so shrinking one won't result in usable space.

Comment: i also tried installing after making a new partition with the shrunk space, but in installation menu it didn't showed the drives i have in my pc.. it showed my whole hard disk as a one partition of 500GB. For which i couldnt proceed with the installation..

Comment: try via fdisk or parted from command line inside the kali installation disk. It should give a better result than the partitioning tool inside the installation application.